# Possible orders of special element in a group

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $G$ be a group. Let $x$ be an element of order $3$ and $y(\neq e)$ be an element of $G$ such that $xyx^{−1} = y^3$. Then what are the all possible order of the element $y$?

**My attempt:**

Since the order of the element $y$ and $y^3$ are same then if order $y$ is finite, then $\gcd (3,n)=1$, i.e $3 \nmid n$. Now consider $H = \left<x\right>$ and $K = \left<y\right>$ then $H,K$ are subgroups of $G$ suppose if $HK$ is a subgroup. If $3\mid (n-1)$ then we can find a group that has order $3n$ and that is non-Abelian. So $n=3k+1$.

Comment: $S_3$ is nonabelian and of order $3\cdot 2$ so I don't know what the end of your argument is supposed to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* We have $x^nyx^{-n}=y^{3^n}$ for all $n\ge 1$. For $n=3$ we have $x^3=e$, so that $y=y^{27}$, i.e., $y^{26}=e$. Now the possible orders are included in the set $\{2,13,26\}$. Note that $y\neq e$.

Comment: order of $y$ can also be $2$. You probably have not seen.

Comment: I have seen it, thank you. I left it our because you say, the order is of the form $3k+1$.